# How to use a Siamese network at test time?

Tags: neural-networks, triplet-loss, siamese

I am trying to understand Siamese networks, and understand how to train them.

Once I have a trained network, I want to know if a new image is close or far to other images in the train set, and fail to understand how to do that.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716616/how-to-deal-with-triplet-loss-when-at-time-of-input-i-have-only-two-files-i-e-a) this question was more or less asked before.

The gist of the answer is:

> compare cosine similarity of vec_base and vec_test in order to
> determine whether base and test are within the acceptable criteria.

[Here](https://youtu.be/6e65XfwmIWE?t=1530), it is suggested to do Nearest Neighbor search.

What I still don't understand is

1. How to get the image(s) to test against? Do I need to find good representatives for each class? What is "good"?
2. Why cosine similarity of all metrics?
3. Doing nearest neighbor over the entire dataset makes no sense, performance-wise - let alone at test time, even with a k-d-tree. Have I missed something fundamental?